# Не выводится строка одна строка через ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>MySite</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="login">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Login" name="login" class="login">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Pass" name="pass" class="pass">
        <input type="submit" value="Enter" class="submit">
    </div>
    <div id="inf">

    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$("document").ready( function() {
    var login = $(".login").val();
    var pass = $(".pass").value;

    $(".submit").click(function() {
        $.ajax ({
            url: "acc.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: ({login1: login, pass1: pass}),
            success: function(data) {
                $("#inf").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$login = $_POST['login1'];
$pass = $_POST['pass1'];

$result = "Login 'n' Pass: ".$login." ".$pass;
echo $result;
?>
```

Почему то не выводится только pass, не знаю как это решить, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("document").ready( function() {

    $(".submit").click(function() {
        var login = $(".login").val();
        var pass = $(".pass").val(); // !!! не $(".pass").value
        $.ajax ({
            url: "acc.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            data: {login1: login, pass1: pass},
            success: function(data) {
                $("#inf").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```